# Trying to write a program / library like LogParser - How does it work internally?

Tags: linq, iis, parsing, logging, logparser

LogParser isn't open source and I need this functionality for an open source project I'm working on.

I'd like to write a library that allows me to query huge (mostly IIS) log files, preferably with Linq.

Do you have any links that could help me? How does a program like LogParser work so fast? How does it handle memory limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably process the information in the log as it reads it. This means it (the library) doesn't have to allocate a huge amount of memory to store the information. It can read a chunk, process it and throw it away. It is a usual and very effective way to process data.

You could for example work line by line and parse each line. For the actual parsing you can write a state machine or if the requirements allows it, use regex.

Another approach would be a state machine that both reads and parses the data. If for some reason a log entry spans more than one line this might be needed.

Some state machine related links:

A **very** simple state machine written in C: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3793

Alot of python related code, but some sections are universally applicable: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python-state.html

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to query IIS log data with LINQ. Then i suggest you to move the Raw IIS Log data to database and query the database using LINQ. This blog post might help.

http://getsrirams.blogspot.in/2012/07/migrate-iislog-data-to-sqlce-4-database.html